# Hugging Face - PyTorch RuntimeError : nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d_index not implemented for Int

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I attempted to fine-tune the `Wav2vec2` model for an audio classification task by following the tutorial at https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/audio_classification and copying and pasting the code provided.

However, when I trained the model, I encountered the following error:

```
nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d_index not implemented for Int.
```

I believe the problem may lie with `PyTorch`. It seems to be working on `Ubuntu WSL 22.04`, but not on `Powershell`.

My system specifications include:

```
- Powershell
- datasets 2.8.0
- transformers 4.25.1
- torch                   1.13.1+cu117
- torchaudio              0.13.1+cu117
- torchvision             0.14.1+cu117
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your target dtype to `torch.int64`.

I received the same error when my target dtype was `torch.int32`. I resolved the issue by adding the following line to my code:

```py
target = target.to(torch.int64)
```